# Content of last-child within group of divs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm going to try and be as clear as I can, but I am quite confused myself so I apologize in advance if I make no sense.

I have a menu of breadcrumbs that looks like this

```
<div class="move">
  <div class="group col-md-2" style="padding:0;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs header" style="margin-top:5em;">
        <li><a>Corporate</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="group col-md-2" style="padding:0;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs header" style="margin-top:5em;">
        <li class='active'><a>Corporate</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="group col-md-2" style="padding:0;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs header" style="margin-top:5em;">
        <li><a>Corporate</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="group col-md-2" style="padding:0;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs header" style="margin-top:5em;">
        <li><a>Corporate</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in my css I have a content tag adding an arrow in between item so they know they can select the next tear. However, I am having more than a little difficulty removing the last-child's content, so the arrow does not appear.

I have tried pretty much everything under the sun that I can think of to remove this tag so some help would be greatly appreciated.

To add the content I am using

```
.move .nav-tabs > li:after{
  content:' > ';
 }
```

I have tried

```
 .move .nav-tabs > li:last-child:after{
   content:' ';
 }

 .move .nav-tabs > li:after:last-child{
   content:' ';
 }

.move .nav-tabs:last-child{
  content:' ';
 }
```

As a note I cannot modify the html to add a class or change it so there are less div's. This is what I have been given to work with. Again any help would be appreciated!

A JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Z77z/

Comment: can you post your HTML and CSS code in a fiddle ?

Comment: how you using in HTML class `.locationsMove`?

Comment: @KheemaPandey Just posted one above

Comment: Yes please, I don't see the div .locationsMove in your code so...

Comment: @KheemaPandey Mistake when I was coping things

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.move > :last-child > .nav-tabs > li:after {
    content:' ';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Z77z/3/

---

As with most CSS3 Selectors, [beware IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Comment: For some reason even though it works in the fiddle, I cannot get this to work in the actual code.

Comment: Nope, not at all. Everything is the same, that is why this has me so confused/frustrated.

Comment: Could there be more children in `.move`? You could try changing `:last-child` to `.group:last-child`.

Comment: Try this: 
`.move .group:last-child .nav-tabs > li:after{
    content: '';
 }`

Comment: The children in .move are the .group divs and it's a dynamic list so there can be many, that is why I was trying to make :last-child work. I tried .group:last-child as well, but that does not want to work either.

Comment: Without seeing an example of code in which this problem is occurring, I can't help you further.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to do it would be to place an id on the li tag that you don't want to show the arrow on, like:

```
<div class="group col-md-2" style="padding:0;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs header" style="margin-top:5em;">
        <li id="noAfterContent"><a>Corporate</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And than css:

```
#noAfterContent:after{
 content:'';
}
```

Comment: Like  I said in my post above, I cannot add anything to the html.

Comment: My bad here try this:
'.move .group:last-child .nav-tabs > li:after{
    content: '';
 }'